# Rails conditions equal to one of an array- Syntax Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, conditional-statements

Hi I am trying to understand why I get a syntax error for this:

:conditions => ["rank = ? and primaries.relationship = ?", ['CPT','SFC'], "Spouse"]

I need to check "rank" against an Array of options.

Seems like this should be pretty simple, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
:conditions => ["rank IN (?, ?) AND primaries.relationship = ?", 'CPT','SFC', "Spouse"]
```